How to nicely log the request object in NestJS?
I am trying to get the request object logged (for debugging purposes). My NestJS application uses express (the default option).
I obtain the request object both in my controller and in the service provider (after injection in the latter case).
Relevant part in the controller is:
  // this is the Logger from @nestjs/common
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MessagesController.name);
  
  @Get()
  findAll(@Req() request: Request): string
  {
    this.logger.log(request);
    return this.messagesService.findAll();
  }

Relevant part in the service provider is:
// the service is request-scoped since it's injected with a request-scoped provider
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class MessagesService {

  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  findAll(): string {
    this.logger.log(this.request);
    return "all messages";
  }

}

In both cases where logging occurs (i.e. both in the controller and the service), the object is logged on the console simply as [object Object] which is not helpful at all.
If the calls to this.logger.log(request) are replaced by mundane console.log(request) the object is nicely printed on the console.
How can I get the Logger from @nestjs/common to nicely print these request objects?

You can override or extend the default logger, but honestly the easiest approach would be to just convert the request to string before logging it:
this.logger.log(JSON.stringify(this.request));

EDIT:
To overcome circular objects, you can use util.inspect:
this.logger.log(util.inspect(this.request));


I guess you mean this.logger.log(JSON.stringify(this.request)). The problem with that is that JSON.stringify fails in the presence of "circular structures" whereas console.log seems to handle them. More importantly I am trying to understand why Logger refuses to print it. Is there perhaps a character limit somewhere? If so, then JSON.stringify would also fail unless the character limit was configurable in which case both Logger.log and console.log would succeed.
